# ReferenceError: cryptoJS is not defined in rails javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cryptojs

i am trying to implement this code to get one of my payment method work but everytime returned with error "Exception occured encryptionString:ReferenceError: cryptoJS is not defined"

the error is due to the code "var key = cryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(keyValue);"

i am running this in rails so please help to advise if there is anything wrong with the code.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'cryptojs-rails', '~> 2.5', '>= 2.5.3'
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require crypto
```

**app/assets/javascripts/maybank.js**

```
var getEncryptionString = function (arrayM2U, envType) {    
try {
    var ITERATIONS = 2;
    var salt='Maybank2u simple encryption';
    var keyValue='000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f';

    var amount = arrayM2U.amount;
    var accountNumber =arrayM2U.accountNumber;
    var payeeCode = arrayM2U.payeeCode;
    var refNum = arrayM2U.refNumber;
    var redirectionurl = arrayM2U.callbackUrl;
    var m_sReqSendString = "";

    if( (accountNumber == undefined || accountNumber == "") && (refNum != undefined &&  refNum != ""))
     m_sReqSendString = 'Login$' +payeeCode+ '$1$' + amount + '$1$' + refNum + '$$$' + redirectionurl;
    else if((accountNumber != undefined && accountNumber != "" ) && (refNum == undefined ||  refNum == ""))
     m_sReqSendString = 'Login$' + payeeCode + '$1$' + amount + '$$$1$' + accountNumber + '$' + redirectionurl;
    else
    m_sReqSendString = 'Login$' + payeeCode + '$1$' + amount + '$1$'+refNum+'$1$' + accountNumber + '$' +redirectionurl ;

    console.log(keyValue);
    var key = cryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(keyValue);
    console.log(keyValue);
    var valueToEnc = null;
    var eValue = m_sReqSendString;
    for (var i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        valueToEnc = salt + eValue;
        var encrypted = cryptoJS.AES.encrypt(valueToEnc, key, {
            mode: cryptoJS.mode.ECB,
            padding: cryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });
        eValue = encrypted;
    }

    var fullEncryptedString = encodeURIComponent(eValue);

    switch (envType) {
      case 1:
          actionUrl = "https://m2upayuat.maybank2u.com.my/testM2uPayment";
          break;
      case 2:
          actionUrl = "https://www.maybank2u.com.my/mbb/m2u/m9006_enc/m2uMerchantLogin.do";
          break;
      default:
          actionUrl = "https://api.maybanksandbox.com/v1.0/testM2uPayment";
    }

    var json = {};

    json.encryptedString = fullEncryptedString;

    json.actionUrl = actionUrl;

        return json;

} catch (err) {
    console.log("Exception occured encryptionString:"+err)
      return "FAIL"

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well I just had a look at the gem source code, it was fast. There's no chance you can get this gem to work. I suppose it was a test by the author, but he must not have given up quickly about it (this is really likely, given that you the github repository has been removed, and there's only been one version of that gem).

The 2.5.3 cryptojs library should contain all those files :

```
⇒  tree tags/2.5.3/src

├── AES.js
├── BlockModes.js
├── Crypto.js
├── CryptoMath.js
├── DES.js
├── HMAC.js
├── MARC4.js
├── MD5.js
├── PBKDF2.js
├── PBKDF2Async.js
├── Rabbit.js
├── SHA1.js
└── SHA256.js

0 directories, 13 files
```

And the gem that you're using only contains the basic files needed for a gem and `Crypto.js`, which is mostly an empty shell at this point, and that is why your code doesn't work.

```
⇒  tree gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/cryptojs-rails-2.5.3/

├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── app
│   └── assets
│       └── javascripts
│           └── crypto.js
└── lib
    ├── cryptojs-rails
    │   └── version.rb
    └── cryptojs-rails.rb

5 directories, 5 files
```

In a nutshell, I think you'll have to import cryptojs in your project through another channel (rails-assets, npm/yarn, bower, manually into vendor or any other means that I couldn't think of).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. so is it ok to just remove the gem since it is of no use? i'm also running rails development in Windows, can advise what is the method to get cryptojs works? thanks.

Comment: Yeah you can remove it. There's only one of the many cryptojs files in this gem, and it won't be enough to use the library anyway. Easiest options : easiest will be to use rails-asset gems like this one that seems quite up-to-date and well-maintained : https://rails-assets.org/#/components/crypto-js. You'll find all the details for setup on this page. You can also add cryptoJS javascript files directly in your vendor directory, you should find tons of tutorials online about this I believe.